# Engel-form of Fibonacci sequences series

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

What is the exact (closed form) value of the expression, where $f_1=f_2=1$ and $f_{n+1}=f_n+f_{n-1}\forall n\ge 2$,$$\dfrac{1}{f_1}+\dfrac{1}{f_1f_2}+\dfrac{1}{f_1f_2f_3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{f_1f_2\cdots f_{\ell}}+\cdots$$
I approximate it by computer that it is about $1.74\dots$ and we know that it is irrational but I don't know how to find its closed form.

I interest this because it is involving the Fiboncci sequences but I haven't seen anything like this that I googled. So it maybe not of interest to others so I would also know (the following dumb questions) that. Why doesn't this one be studied or why does it not be interested?

Comment: "*we know that it is irrational*" Would you have a reference for that?

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A101689](https://oeis.org/A101689) with value $2.70450289915406748719754896618187978517783483136...$. There does not seem to be a closed form.

Comment: @dxiv https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_expansion I think because it's infinite engel expansion.

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn Thank you.